# Cygwin ssh-host-config on windows for hadoop

Tags: windows, eclipse, hadoop, cygwin

I'm new to cygwin and hadoop, please anyone could explain

- which mirror link is the proper to install cygwin
- what version of hadoop is bug free ( `.sh` works good )
- is it must to run below commands before running `ssh-host-config`

  - $ chmod +r  /etc/passwd
  - $ chmod u+w /etc/passwd
  - $ chmod +r  /etc/group
  - $ chmod u+w /etc/group
  - $ chmod 755 /var
  - $ touch /var/log/sshd.log
  - $ chmod 664 /var/log/sshd.log

  or http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/
- for `ssh-host-config` what all options should i give yes and no for running sshd service and hadoop proper
- "Please enter the password for user 'cyg_server'? " if i do configuration does it necessary to login with `cyg_server` user id, else for running hadoop `all.sh` asking for password and the given password is not accepting too.
- once i tried to connect, I could do till all process to run, tried to connect through Eclipse, but it shows `connection failed to localhost`.

Till now I was going through different tutorials, if cygwin part goes fine then will get issue with hadoop, else get stuck with cygwin itself.

If any one could guide right way, will be helpful and even could give suggestions.

Comment: Any Cygwin Mirror link will work, there's no difference in files (usually). I can't speak to the hadoop configuration. You may want to try Hadoop's forums for help on configuration.